# Save text to server-side file in HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap to build a small website. To narrow my question, assume that this is the only element in the entire webpage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="shadow-lg container align-items-center rounded rounded-3 border-2 d-none d-md-block"
        style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;width: 600px;justify-content:center;">
        <div class="justify-content-center d-flex pt-3">
        <p class="text-center"><strong>What brings you to my website?</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="justify-content-center d-flex" action="log.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="whatBrings" style="width: 400px;" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="justify-content-center d-flex">
        <div class="text-center">
        <button type="button" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary my-3">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

My JavaScript for handling the Submit button:

```js
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitButton");
var whatBrings = document.getElementById("whatBrings");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("Button was clicked");

    //store whatBrings.value in server-side file here

    whatBrings.value = ""; //reset text box
});
```

How would I store the string `whatBrings.value` in a server-side file? A solution in JavaScript would be preferable, but PHP would work as well.

Comment: Do you have any PHP code? What have you tried?

Comment: I am not very familiar with PHP; I have tried experimenting with `file_put_contents`, however, I really do not know how to "sync"/send information between a JavaScript file and a PHP script.

Comment: JS in HTML is executed in frontend (visitors browser), and as such it cannot directly write to the backend/server side... if it did, that would be very bad.. One way to do it is to send this value via POST or GET request (you can use AJAX requests here) to a php file, which can handle then this value on the backend (like save it to  a DB). There are plenty of tutorials on all of these steps... I would assume you did not do a comprehensive research before asking for a ready solution here..

Comment: You would either use a [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) or [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX).

Comment: I'll look into both; thanks to both of you for your time and sorry if my question was structured badly!